# 2020 Altima compressor Doesn’t Engage [B20C7-15]

Tags: ac, nissan, altima, compressor

I have A 2020 Altima Platinum, the compressor is not working, went to the workshop, gas is okay, compressor is fine, but they told me to change the IPDM, changed it “with the same code” the compressor started to work, after few hours, i turned the car on, the compressor is not working, went to the workshop, they did a computer diagnostic test, it’s showing “(B20C7-15) fault: A/C clutch [circ short to batt or open]”, they erased the fault and the compressor started to work, then after one day it stopped working again, went to erase the fault again and it started to work, today stopped working, after visiting different workshops, no one would tell what is the problem, i need to know where to start! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Was this ac system serviced by you, repair shop or Nissan dealer? If you or a repair shop serviced the ac system, was refrigerant/sealer used? Ac parts replaced, in or out of warranty? Unless you have refrigeration gauges and familiar with ac operating pressures, guessing can mislead anyone into assumptions. Personally, I believe 98% of vehicle ac system problems are the leaks owners don't address as diyers but will run to stores for the refill kit containing sealer, hoping to save money on expensive repairs. Unfamiliarity with vehicle ac systems can result in using sealer and either over or under charging a system when more often than not, sealer fails and the system continues to leak. Sealer damages systems and never used by reputable dealers and repair shops. Ac systems have built-in protection to its compressor using a pressure sensor, sending signals to the engine computer; when loss of refrigerant is below optimum, compressor damage can result. Lubricating oil is continually circulating as a mist by refrigerant in its liquid phase. When refrigerant is lost thru a leak, less and less lube oil returns to the compressor and if allowed to run this way, will destroy itself quickly. The pressure sensor prevents this from occurring. Refrigeration gauges are used to monitor pressures in determining if operating pressures are correct or not. Electronics monitor sensors and generate error codes trained techs/mechanics use to narrow their search for a problem.